# Is this problem NP-hard？Or what kind of mathematical problem does it belong to?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, linear-programming, discrete-optimization, np-complete

Assuming there are n types of gifts, each with a number of $a_n$. Now we have to pack them into gift packs, each containing several types of gifts, and each gift has only one.If a gift package containing k types of gifts is marked as $b_k$, how to find the packaging method with the highest total score. Note that $b_k$ may not be monotonous.

For the special case where size(b)=1,I find a solution:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/program-to-find-maximum-number-of-k-sized-groups-with-distinct-type-items-are-possible-in-python, It may seem like a greedy algorithm, but I haven't provided a standardized proof of its correctness

For example, mark the four types of gifts as A B C D,a=[5,2,3,2],b=[1,3,6,0],

method:[A B C][A B C][A C D][A D][A]
value:22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this variant of the [cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $G=\{0,1,2,3\}$ be the set of gifts.  Let $P=\{1,\dots,2^{|G|}-1\}$ be the set of all possible nonempty packs, with the binary representation of $p\in P$ indicating which gifts appear in pack $p$.  For $g\in G$, let $P_g \subset P$ be the set of packs that contain gift $g$.  Let $c_p$ denote the number of gifts in pack $p$.  Let binary decision variable $x_p$ indicate whether pack $p$ is used.  The problem is to maximize $$\sum_{p\in P} b_{c_p} x_p$$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{p\in P_g} x_p = a_g \quad \text{for all $g\in G$}$$

For your example instance, an optimal solution is $x_p=1$ for $p\in \{1,5,7,11,13\}$ and $x_p=0$ otherwise, with optimal objective value $$b_1+b_2+b_3+b_3+b_3 = 1+3+6+6+6 = 22,$$ as you claimed.

For a large number of gifts, a [column generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_generation) approach will typically be more efficient.

Comment: thanks a lot ^v^. Maybe i haven't fully understand the knowledge, shouldn't xp be more than binary decision variable but also indicate the number of pack p?

Comment: @ZhuJerry I had assumed from your example that only one copy of each pack can be used.  If you want to allow more, then change $x_p$ to a nonnegative integer decision variable.  For the example instance, the resulting optimal objective value is still $22$, but there are two additional optimal solutions: $x_1=x_9=x_{13}=1,x_7=2$ and $x_1=x_3=x_7=1,x_{13}=2$

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Knapsack Problem; had to do these back when I did my Masters in Computer Science. Some Knapsack Problems can be solved in polynomial time using a technique called Dynamic Programming. Yours sounds like a pretty common case that can be solved with Dynamic Programming. Others variations of the Knapsack Problem can be NP-Complete.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem